# Shorter way to write find_by_slug("test").id in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails ActiveRecord helpers, is there a shorter way to just get the id column by searching another column.

Currently:

`find_by_slug("test").id`

**Update**

Based on the answer below, the find_by_ functions are deprecated in Rails 4. Is there a more succinct way to write the following (since I have a LOT of these):

```
QUESTION    = where(slug: "question").pluck(:id).first
ANSWER      = where(slug: "answer").pluck(:id).first
NOTE        = where(slug: "note").pluck(:id).first
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only after a single field, use [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck):

```
where(slug: "test").pluck(:id).first
```

Assuming `slug` is unique, `pluck(:id)` will return an array with 1 element (or 0 elements if no matching slug is found).

Additionally, the magic `find_by_*` methods are deprecated in Rails 4. You shouldn't be using them.

Comment: Is there any difference between doing `.pluck(:id)` and just `.id`?

Comment: Is there a shorter way to write all this? I have updated the question with your answer.

Comment: Why are you so obsessed with "shorter"? This is the *best* way to write this, length doesn't matter as much as readability. If you really want shorter, take the above code an made a function.